# Solving $-z e^{-z} = (x-z) e^{x-z}$ with $x,z \neq 0$

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

I have an equation $$-z e^{-z} = (x-z) e^{x-z}$$ where $z=\frac{r S}{P}$ and $x=\frac{r y (P-S)}{P}$. I know that $-z \in (-\infty,-1)$ and $x-z \in (-1,0)$ with $x \neq 0$. Is there any way to solve this to find an expression for S?

Of course, $x-z = W(-z e^{-z})$, but as far as I can see this does not bring me any closer.

Comment: When you apply Lambert $W$ at both sides you'll get $-z=x-z$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ (x-z)\, e^{x-z}+z\, e^{-z} =0 \tag 1$$
where
$$z=\frac{r S}{P}\qquad \text{and} \qquad  x=\frac{r y (P-S)}{P}$$

Replace $x$ and $z$ in $(1)$; simplifying, what remains is
$$e^{\frac{r y (P-S)}{P}}=\frac {(1+y)S+Py } S$$ Divide each side by $e^{r y}$ to obtain
$$\large\color{blue}{e^{-\frac{r  y}{P}S}=\frac{(1+y)} {e^{r y}}\,\frac{S+\frac{Py}{1+y} }S}$$ which, for $S$, has a solution in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the linked paper).

If, on the search bar of the site, you type `generalized Lambert function`, you should find $225$ results.